# How to create a jar file with maven for JavaFx8 and spring

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, javafx, executable-jar

For two days I try to make an executable jar file from my project that I wrote with spring and JavaFx. I tried to do that with different ways and plugins like com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin, exec-maven-plugin, maven-shade plugin and etc. 
It is possible to deploy spring and JavaFx? How can you do that?

Edited Part:

I found the problem. The needed spring classes wasnt exist in the jar file. So I added spring-boot-maven-plugin and after that every thing was ok. A lot of thanks for Lord Windy!

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-jar-file-with-maven/ is a tutorial on making a jar with maven.

Comment: I know this website. The problem is not to create jar file with maven but how to include JavaFx 8 in this jar file

Comment: I don't think anybody here can help you anymore than just providing a link to the JavaFX Maven plugin documentation (which describes how to package JavaFX projects using Maven, so yes, this is possible): http://zenjava.com/javafx/maven/.  To get concrete assistance for specific issues, you usually need to include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), environment information and full error traces in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I can put this as an answer now that you have given me the magic word 'JavaFX 8'. [As of Java 7 update 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/index.html) Javafx is included in the JRE. So if you want to include JavaFX on a computer that doesn't have it, you will need to bundle the JRE with the Jar. [In which case, this here explains how to bundle the JRE](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/tycho-user/msg03054.html)

EDIT:

You seem to be having trouble with the actual project and not the Java stuff so I have done up a small example project with [accompanying Jar for you.](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=C02317F6BD345A66%21334)

```
package local.brown;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Created by Sam on 12/8/2014.
 */
public class Main extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setTitle("TraderRL");
    Parent root = null;
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();

    root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml_game.fxml").openStream());
    WindowController dc = loader.getController();
    dc.setLabel("New");
    Scene myScene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(myScene);
    primaryStage.show();
    dc.setLabel("New22");

  }



  public static void main(String[] args){
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

This here is the Controller you were talking about

```
package local.brown;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

/**
 * Created by Sam on 12/9/2014.
 */
public class WindowController implements Initializable {

  @FXML private Label label;
  @FXML private Canvas canvas;

  public void setLabel(String s){
    label.setText(s);
  }

  public void  initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

  }
}
```

FXML document that I think you would be using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas?>


      <BorderPane id="BorderPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="local.brown.WindowController">

          <top>
              <HBox style="-fx-background-color: #336699;">
                  <Label fx:id="label" text="Page Title"/>
              </HBox>
          </top>
        <center>
              <Canvas fx:id="canvas" width="1024" height="768" />
          </center>
      </BorderPane>
```

Comment: My computer use JDK, JRE 1.8. I thought that was clear when I said JavaFx 8, sorry for that.

Comment: I honestly don't understand the problem then, FX8 is included in Java 8. FX has been included in Java since the link I posted. You can't bundle it, you just write the source file with an import and if you want to ensure that the user can run it you include a copy of the JRE.

Comment: Ok, I think now my problem is not with packaging from Javafx but because the structure from Javafx. the error now when I try open the jar file is: Missing JavaFX application class com/project/test/App. I have 3 Fxml and 3 controller (MenuController, LeftController, RightController). Maybe I have to create main fxml with main controller and put in it all other 3 controllers. I still do not know how can I do that.

Comment: I can't do this thing for you, but this here is a working example.